# Factorise vector into product of matrix and vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've looked for answers to my question, but I'm not sure I know what I'm looking for.

I have a linear system $\vec{v} = \mathbf{V}\vec{\dot{\theta}}$

I already have $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{\dot{\theta}}$ is a vector of variables. I want to factorise $\vec{v}$ and get $\mathbf{V}$. Does this process have some particular name? Could anyone point my in the direction of both some info on it and how to do this in Matlab?

Many thanks!

Comment: There is a chance there exist many different such $\bf V$, you can write it as a linear least squares problem. $\|\bf v - V\theta\|_2^2$ for example with Kronecker products and vectorization.

Comment: You say you have a linear system $\vec{v} = \mathbf{V}\vec{\dot{\theta}}$. But obviously you don't have $\mathbf{V}$ since that is what you are trying to find. So exactly what information are you refering to when you say you have $\vec v$? Do you mean you have formulas for the components of $\vec v$ in terms of the variables in $\vec{\dot{\theta}}$?